# Can't launch a WebMap Activity(NullPointerException)

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I have found [this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/WebView/GeoWeb2/src/com/commonsware/android/geoweb2/GeoWebTwo.java) of the well knowen `commonsware`. I tried to launch it but i have a NullPointer Exception:
Here is the code:

```
public class WebMapActivity extends Activity {
      private static String PROVIDER="gps";
      private WebView browser;
      private LocationManager myLocationManager=null;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        myLocationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

       browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.addJavascriptInterface(new Locater(), "locater");
        browser.loadUrl("http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles-android-webmap/simple-android-map.html");
      }

      @Override
      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(PROVIDER, 0,
                                                  0,
                                                  onLocation);
      }

      @Override
      public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        myLocationManager.removeUpdates(onLocation);
      }

      LocationListener onLocation=new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder("javascript:whereami(");

          buf.append(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
          buf.append(",");
          buf.append(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
          buf.append(")");

          browser.loadUrl(buf.toString());
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
          // required for interface, not used
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
          // required for interface, not used
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                      Bundle extras) {
          // required for interface, not used
        }
      };

      public class Locater {
        public String getLocation() throws JSONException {
          Location loc=myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(PROVIDER);

          if (loc==null) {
            return(null);
          }

          JSONObject json=new JSONObject();

          json.put("lat", loc.getLatitude());
          json.put("lon", loc.getLongitude());

          return(json.toString());
        }
      }
    }
```

Logcat:

```
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gatec.tunisiana/com.android.airplane.WebMapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.android.airplane.WebMapActivity.onCreate(WebMapActivity.java:26)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  ... 11 more
```

I don't know why it can't launchs the activity. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do you have a WebView in your main.xml that is named webview?

Comment: @ByteMe: OOOOOO no no no! What i did is horrible ! How i did not noticed that? Thank you very much dude. What a mistake !! Pfff

Comment: @ByteMe: You can answer the post and i'll accept it for future purposes ;). Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you got your answer. For future reference, look at your logs. I know you posted them but the real answer is like midway through.

```
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-29 22:10:35.096: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.android.airplane.WebMapActivity.onCreate(WebMapActivity.java:26)
```

On the second line it says `.WebMapActivity.onCreate(WebMapActivity.java:26)` so you know it's in the WebMapActivity in the onCreate() at line 26. Go to that line and find out what is a `null` value that is critical to that line.

Like ByteMe said...

```
browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Nothing in that line could cause a NullPointerException, unless there was no webview to be found.

Comment: Thank you :). The problem now is i don't know how to center the map to a predefined point and how to add overlay. I never used Map API V3 before...

Comment: I actually haven't spent any time working with the Map API's. I'm not certain, but I think you will probably have to create another question to get this answer, since no one will wander in a NullPointerQuestion hoping to answer a Map API question :/. I'll look around and if I find anything I'll try and point you in the right direction. But I'm not even completely sure what you're asking. What do you mean center at a point? You can use layouts to center layout items.

Comment: I mean that when launching the map it will center in a certain point. Thank you for helping.